# Are there time parameters for when 10 people have to combine for Shemone Esrei?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, time, tefillah-betzibbur

Say you have a minyan, and when the Chazzan starts Shemone Esrei, 8 of the others are up to that point and begin as well, but the others aren’t yet up to Shemone Esrei. Is that a problem for the 9 saying it in regards to Tefilla B’Tzibbur?

What if one of the 9 finish their personal Shemone Esrei before they even get someone else to start? Would he be considered to have davened “b’yichidus”?

This situation can happen very easily with a 10 person minyan and one of them is far behind. I am curious if the minyan should wait for him so they have 10 saying it together, or should they go ahead and daven regardless of when he eventually will be up to his own Shemone Esrei?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need all of the other 9 to be able to answer אמן etc

Comment: There are many who say a majority (6) davening together is sufficient. But I think they all have to be davening at the same time; some even say they have to start together.